# JSP dynamic dependent select box

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, jsp

I am looking for a method to create a dynamic dependent select box in a JSP, preferably something AJAX/JQuery based so I don't have to make a separate trip to the server.  I am updating an internal auditing page for my organization and adding a feature to allow for a 're-audit'.  The first select box is populated on page load and is listing of all employees and the second, populated dynamically, should be a listing of the previous audits for the selected employee.

Comment: What you have tried so far to achieve that?

Comment: Nothing yet as I am not that well versed with AJAX or jQuery.  I am thinking I may have to pass the employee id as a parameter on a reload.

Comment: "on a reload"? That sounds like you're planning to use ajax to call the same page again. Don't do that. Make separate pages (or a servlet or servlets rather) for returning the dropdowns in response to ajax calls. Then call those via ajax, have it return the options, and just use javascript in the main page to stick them in the select.

Comment: Since I am very unknowledgable about ajax I was going to reload the page with a parameter as an alternative.  Are there any tut's out there that explain the technique you described?

Comment: Use jQuery ajax for your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this in your javascript (do not forget to import latest stable version of `jquery`),

```
$(document).ready(function() {    //This will be triggered on page ready
  jQuery.ajax({
     type: "POST",     //Passing data in post method
     url: "ServletURL",   //Servlet URL
     data: "userId=" + $("#userId").val(),   //Post if you need to send anything
     success: function (response) {    //Ajax success data
         alert("Details loaded successfully!!!");
     },
     error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) { //Ajax failure data
         alert(xhr.status);
         alert(thrownError);
      }
   });
});
```

And process the userId in servlet and transfer the resulted data into any jsp page, where you can convert your result into the type either `json or xml` for your comfort. This data will be returned as `response` in ajax success.